# Is it BAD or GOOD idea to validate constructor parameters in constructor method of an immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, immutability

You have an immutable object, and you set its internal variables in the constructor which accepts couple of parameters.

**Question**:
Do you see any problems to VALIDATE constructor parameters in the constructor method of an immutable object and throw `ArgumentExceptions` if not valid?

(to me it makes sense but I wanted to ask in case there are some better ways or something not OK with this - for example if it is a better design to move validation from constructor to a factory)

**Or if I generalize it by rephrasing the question**:

Is it OK to put business rules-wise logic in the constructor methods? Or should constructors always do nothing more than setting object's internals?

Thanks

Comment: Small point on terminology... a default constructor is auto-generated by the compiler in the absence of a user-supplied constructor and is parameterless.

Comment: Thanks, I have deleted the 'default' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a way, it makes sense to validate in the constructor itself because you know that all usages of it will pass through that single point, and any other developer that will use your code will be protected from making mistakes because of your "low-level" validations.

If you move the validation higher up the call chain, you leave the class code cleaner but you expose the code to the possibility of "you're using it wrong" bugs.

Comment: Perhaps you can get the best of both options by using a static factory method on the class itself, and making the constructor private?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution that would match both wishes.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor validation has a slight problem in case of invalid data: What do you do then? You *have to* throw an exception, which might be awkward and also a performance hit, if you create "invalid" instances often.

To get rid of `try ... catch` every time you instantiate the object, you would have to create a factory anyway.

I think the factory is a good approach, but in a slightly different way - validate the arguments given to the factory method and only then create a (valid) instance.

Answer (score 3):

A class should, to the best of it's ability, document the guarantees it makes, and do its best to keep itself in a valid state at all times. Any incoming calls that are either inappropriate or would put the object in an invalid state should generate exceptions.

This holds true for constructors too. A constructor that doesn't validate its inputs makes it possible for others to create invalid instances of your class. But if you always validate, then anyone with a reference to your class can be confident that it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I'd validate the parameters before I pass them into the constructor. You never know how your code is going to evolve so doing the validation in a factory as you suggest should provide a bit more visibility and feels 'cleaner'.

Comment: However, doing this, every caller must write her own code for validation. There is almost no chance that all such pieces of code will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice for where to raise an exception, just go with wherever you're more likely to remember to surround it with a `try..catch`, it helps to consider other users of your codebase too. This more often then not depends on the purpose of the class, and how you see it being used. However consistency is also important.

Sometimes it's useful to not raise exceptions in either and instead have a separate `ValidateInstance()` function for immutable types. Your other choices are as you say class creation (via factory or constructor) or on class usage (usually a bad idea if an error can be thrown sooner.. but sometimes makes sense).

putting them in the constructor has the advantage that they will also surface in a Factory method, if you chose to make one later.

HTH